# Adapting existing win usb driver for LabVIEW

Tags: driver, labview

I have a specific USB device that has it's own driver for Win7.
It works fine in my .NET application, I'm using drivers functions (C++) to manipulate device.

Now I'm trying to get this device work in LabVIEW.
Is there a way to somehow adapt existing driver for it? Or it is useless and I need to write completely new driver for LabVIEW?

For now I created a driver using "NI-VISA Driver Wizard" so that "NI MAX" and "NI-VISA Interactive Control" detect my device. But I don't know what to do next?

Comment: Is there a dll associated with the driver?

Comment: No. Only .c and .h files for including in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the driver C source files as a dll.

https://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-VC/How-to-create-a-DLL-file-from-a-C-file/td-p/866863

Then import the dll into LabVIEW.

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DCB90714981A1F148625731E00797C33

As highlighted by Prain, the following is an example describing how C/ dll can be used in LabVIEW

https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Using-Existing-C-Code-or-a-DLL-in-LabVIEW/ta-p/3499233

Comment: Thanks! That's the way I'm going... Though it is not clear for me yet, how to make proper .dll - Visual Studio compiler shows lots of errors, when I try to make .dll file. But it is different task.

Comment: @Prain If you post the instrument name, I can take a look at the driver...

Comment: That would be great! If I understand you correctly... I'm using VisualStudio 2010 to create .dll file by this instruction: [link](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Using-Existing-C-Code-or-a-DLL-in-LabVIEW/ta-p/3499233). Then I have a device with drivers in this archive: [link](http://elcus.ru/files/arinc/ece0206_1win_v2.1.1.rar) In "driver" folder there is an example with OpenECE0206ByIndex.cpp file. Currently that file I can't compile into .dll

Comment: For now I managed to compile .dll out of that .cpp file. There was a linker problem I solved. Now will try to use this .dll in LabView. Thanks for your advices. I leave previous comment in case you wold like to see.

Comment: @Prain Hi Prain, if you're happy with the answer above, can you accept it?